# Magento 2: Get product ID in override getTierPriceList from TierPrice

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, preference, override-model

I'm extending \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice to return a custom list of tier prices for products. But I can't seem to figure out how to get the product id that is calling the getTierPriceList method. Any suggestions?

My di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice" type="MyCompany\Pricing\Model\Plugin\TierPrice" />
</config>
```

TierPrice class:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Pricing\Model\Plugin;

class TierPrice extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice
{
    public function getTierPriceList()
    {
        //custom code goes here, return original for now.
        return parent::getTierPriceList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are extending `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice` you can access the protected property `$product` with:

`$productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();`

The `$product` property is set in the constructor of `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPrice` which `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice` extends.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't realize you could use $this in this context. I assumed it would be the extended class.